# Gmail doesn't load new messages after replying

Tags: sync, gmail

For some time now I have been experiencing this issue. After having replied to any email, I can sync and see new messages in my inbox but if I click on them to actually read them I just see my last reply.

Anyone having this issue? What could be the problem?